# Set restrictions for files in /public folder with rails and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using paperclip for image storage, and i have a problem. When the file is uploaded, paperclip generates two files, a processed image with a watermark and the original file, in this case the image files are in public folder, now the question is, can i restric the url in case the user enter into it like:

```
localhost:3000/files/photos/image_processeds/57308cd52cb1be0846e4be9f/original/image.png
```

If the user enter into the link, it will be forbidden.

This is my paperclip config

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :image_original,
                        :url => "/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                        :path => ":rails_root/public/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

and

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :image_processed,
                        processors: [:watermark],
                        styles: {
                            thumb: ['150x150', :jpg],
                            small: ['350x300', :jpg],
                            medium: ['550x500', :jpg],
                            original: {geometry: '60%',watermark_path: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/logo.gif", position: "Center"}
                        },
                        :url => "/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                        :path => ":rails_root/public/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Theres is a way to do it or maybe find a better approach for that?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're storing them in `/public` to start with?

Answer (score 0):

The `original/image.png` should be watermarked I guess. 
I mean the version without watermark should not exist after processing.
Did you check it?

Comment: The problem here is about the original image without watermark, it needs stay in the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, a reliable solution is save a copy of the original image into the database and grant access to it only when they purchase the photo, otherwise they only can see the copies with watermark :)